# How to transfer account to PDA

Tags: rust, anchor, solana

I have a deposit_sol_collateral_account like this and i want to transfer it to a PDA. Its just an account that receives sol and locks it. Most of the examples i saw for PDAS have to do with accounts that have some sort of minting. The collateral account does not mint anything. I need help how do i transfer to pda in this case or i use thesame example to transfer ownership.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeObligation<'info> {
    #[account(signer)]
    authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    //#[account(mut)]
    //dashboard: Account<'info, Dashboard>,
    #[account(zero)]
    obligation: Account<'info, Obligation>,
    //     // Where SOL will be locked
    //#[account(init, payer = authority, space = 320)]
    deposit_sol_collateral_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
//     //     // Where all stablecoin lenders are depositing

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DepositCollateral<'info> {
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'info>,

    // Global state
    #[account(mut)]
    pub global_state: ProgramAccount<'info, GlobalStateData>,

    // Trove state
    #[account(mut)]
    pub trove: ProgramAccount<'info, TroveData>,

    // Where SOL will be locked
    #[account(mut)]
    pub deposit_sol_collateral_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}



    pub fn depositcollateral(ctx: Context<DepositCollateral>, amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        let from = &mut ctx.accounts.owner;
        let to = &mut ctx.accounts.deposit_sol_collateral_account;

        let lamports = sol_to_lamports(amount as f64);

        let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
            &from.to_account_info().key,
            &to.to_account_info().key,
            lamports,
        );

        let res = anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
            &ix,
            &[
                from.to_account_info().clone(),
                to.to_account_info().clone(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.clone(),
            ],
        )?;

        msg!("Result {:?}", res);

        let obligation = &mut ctx.accounts.obligation;
        obligation.deposited_sol += amount;

        let global_state = &mut ctx.accounts.global_state;
        global_state.deposited_sol += amount;

        msg!("Trove Data {:?}", (obligation.deref_mut()));
        msg!("Global Data {:?}", (global_state.deref_mut()));
            
            Ok(())
    }
```

this is the example i saw should i follow thesame process eventhough my account is not a mint type

```
      pub fn exchange(ctx: Context<Exchange>) -> ProgramResult {
        // Transferring from initializer to taker
        let (_pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[ESCROW_PDA_SEED], ctx.program_id);
        let seeds = &[&ESCROW_PDA_SEED[..], &[bump_seed]];

        token::transfer(
            ctx.accounts
                .into_transfer_to_taker_context()
                .with_signer(&[&seeds[..]]),
            ctx.accounts.escrow_account.initializer_amount,
        )?;

        token::transfer(
            ctx.accounts.into_transfer_to_initializer_context(),
            ctx.accounts.escrow_account.taker_amount,
        )?;

        token::set_authority(
            ctx.accounts
                .into_set_authority_context()
                .with_signer(&[&seeds[..]]),
            AuthorityType::AccountOwner,
            Some(ctx.accounts.escrow_account.initializer_key),
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<'info> Exchange<'info> {
    fn into_transfer_to_taker_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Transfer<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: self.pda_deposit_token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
            to: self.taker_receive_token_account.to_account_info().clone(),
            authority: self.pda_account.clone(),
        };
        let cpi_program = self.token_program.to_account_info();
        CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the first example from? I’d be usefull for me. Thx